# Stop HTML5 Audio/Video on Parent Class Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, video

I have here a Slick Slider that mostly contains images, but an audio and video element as well.

All of the "slides", when visible, have the class "slick-current" when they are displayed using the generated navigation. The problem I' need help with is how to stop the audio and/or video elements within each slide when the slide removes the class "slick-current".

I know how to call the audio and video elements with jQuery, but I'm lost on how to call something when a class has been removed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What event removes the class? Some random click?

Comment: Perform the action on all slides but the slide with the current class `if (!$(AllSlidesSelector).hasClass("slick-current")) {` ?

Comment: there is a right and left navigation that controls the next and previous slides.

Comment: @theblackgigant, fantastic! but when and where do I call this? I don't want this running constantly, correct?

Comment: HOLD THE PHONE - there's a beforeChange API callback that will allow me to check if the slide has the slide-current class.  I think this'll solve my issue.  Thanks everyone for getting the wheels rolling this early in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there's no way to do an event on 'CSS class added/removed' as far as I know. But speaking about Slick Slider from http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/, you can attach an onchange event when the slides are about to change. You can use the 'beforechange' or 'afterchange' events.

```
$('#slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
   // stop the video/audio inside currentSlide if you need to
}
```

Comment: this is what I found out.  But I'm having an issue trying to find the audio or video element within the currentSlide.  a simple `currentSlide.find("audio").pause();` gives an error of `currentSlide.find is not a function`

Comment: Because currentSlide might not be a jQuery object, try $(currentSlide).find('audio')?

Comment: and `$(currentSlide).find("audio").pause();` renders and error of  `$(...).find(...).pause` is not a function

Comment: the currentSlide and nextSlide are accessing the slide's data-slick-index attribute that the carousel is appending to each slide.

Comment: Try this - $(currentSlide).find("audio")[0].pause();

Comment: Well, does every slide has an audio tag? If not, you have to do a check of what you want to accomplish. If there is no audio tag, then $(currentSlide).find("audio")[0] will be undefined, and basically you are trying to do undefined.pause(), which is not possible.

Comment: that makes sense, but how?? I'm getting stuck on the proper call here.

Comment: Well you want to check whether the element exists. Hint - try the 'length' function.

Comment: I did that... gave me the `length is not a function` BS.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT!

using the method that's documented for beforeChange, I ran into the issue of accessing the contents of the currentSlide.  So I did a little more digging and voila:

```
if ($("[data-slick-index='" +currentSlide+ "']").find("audio").length > 0)}      
     //turn off the audio
}
```

I was able to test this with a simple console.log, if the slide had an audio element, then say "HAS AUDIO".  Thanks to @Ken-D-Timothy for helping me out.